# How do I bind a ListView to an ObservableCollection in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, data-binding, c++-cli

I've got a small app which will allow the user to select a number of files and then perform some processing. I was thinking I'd collect the files in an `ObservableCollection` of `String^` (and probably expand this to a full class at a later date).

The problem is I can't work out how to bind the `ListView` to the `ObservableCollection`. I've added a property to the main form:

```
protected:
    ObservableCollection<String^>^ m_sourceFiles;

public:
    property ObservableCollection<String^>^ SourceFileList
    {
        ObservableCollection<String^>^ get() {return m_sourceFiles;}
    }
```

All the examples I've seen for C# / VB implementations switch to using XAML at this point, but I can't see how to do that in C++? Where do I go from here?

Comment: What kind of ListView?  Windows Forms, I presume, that's a no-go.

Comment: Yes, windows forms. Is there some other way to bind data to a Windows forms object?

Comment: Windows Forms doesn't use XAML, WPF does.  Give an example of the C# code you want to duplicate with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `DataSource` property on `DataGridView`, `ListBox`, and `ComboBox`.  Can you use one of those?  `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` doesn't have support for data-binding.  However, you can use virtual mode and handle the [RetrieveVirtualItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.retrievevirtualitem.aspx) event.

Comment: +1/Accepted: A `DataGridView` looks like it should work fine - cheers.

Comment: Also be aware that data binding in WinForms used the `IBindingList` interface (there's a `BindingList` class to use if you don't need custom behavior).  I presume that `ObservableCollection` is a WPF thing.